# nested list in PHP

Tags: php, list, nested

I'm attempting to create a list of employees and the tasks that have been assigned to them for the day.  I believe the issue is with passing the variable from one query to another, but I can't seem to resolve the issue.  This should be fairly easy, I'm just not catching it.  My code is below:

```
<table class="table mb-0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th>Employee</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
                                    
        $ret=mysqli_query($con,"select DISTINCT a.id, a.fullname, b.employee_id from tbluser a, tbltasks b where a.id = b.employee_id order by a.fullname;");   
        $cnt=1;
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret)) {
    ?>
                                
        <table class="table mb-0">
            <tr>
                <td><?php  echo " $row[employee_id] - $row[fullname] ";?></td>
                                                            
                    <table class="table mb-0">
                                                            
                    <?php
                        $today = date('Y-m-d');
                            
                        $ret=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tbltasks where date = '$today' 
                             and employee_id = $employee_id");  
                        $cnt=1;
                        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret)) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php  echo " $row[project_id] - $row[estimated_time] ";?></td>
                                                                
                    </tr>
                                                                
                    <?php 
                        $cnt=$cnt+1;
                    }?>
                    
                </table>
                                                            
            </tr>
                                                                            
            <?php 
                $cnt=$cnt+1;
            }?>
                                                    

            </table>
            </table>
```

Thanks for any help that you can provide!

Comment: Hey, for next time, always let us know what issue you're having in extreme detail, otherwise helping is hard. This code is short, so I can try.

I notice that `$employee_id` is never defined, did you mean `$row[employee_id]`? Also if you aren't having trouble with reusing `$row` now, you will very soon. ALWAYS use distinct variable names.

Not directly related: putting a table inside another table is almost always not correct. The order goes table -> thead / tbody -> tr -> th / td.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below code will resolve your issue.

you missed many single quotes and have some errors in queries.

```
   <?php
                                
    $reta=mysqli_query($con,"select DISTINCT a.id, a.fullname, b.employee_id from tbluser a, tbltasks b where a.id = b.employee_id order by a.fullname asc");   
    $cnta=1;
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($reta)) {
       $employee_id = $row['employee_id'];
   ?>
                            
    <table class="table mb-0">
        <tr>
            <td><?php  echo $row['employee_id']." - ".$row['fullname'];?></td>
                                                        
                <table class="table mb-0">
                                                        
                <?php
                    $today = date('Y-m-d');
                        
                    $retb=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tbltasks where date = '$today' AND employee_id = '$employee_id'");  
                    $cntb=1;
                    while ($data=mysqli_fetch_array($retb)) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php  echo $data['project_id']." - ". $data['estimated_time'];?></td>
                                                            
                </tr>
                                                            
                <?php $cntb++; } ?>
                
            </table>
                                                        
        </tr>
                                                                        
        <?php $cnta++; } ?>
```

Comment: nice to hear that it helped you... thank you